# Get value on click

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk3

I need to get a value when I click on a text, but it seems that for some reason, the pointer gets lost and returns a random value, I want to do this:

```
static void click(GtkWidget* widget, long* click){
 cout << "Long value is: " << *click << endl;
}

int main(){
   gtk_init(0,0);
   //......... MORE CODE ......
   GtkWidget* label  = gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_label(text);
   long value = 50509;
   g_signal_connect(label, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(click), &value);
   //......... MORE CODE ......
   gtk_main();
}
```

(C++ 14)
can anybody help me?

Comment: Where did you get that function signature for `click`? Check [the manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) to see what parameters are passed. You are actually using the `event` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, it was something totally simple, when I pass a value in the function, g_signal_connect, it becomes a gpointer, a pointer supports 32bits of data, while the long consumes 64bits, I changed long to int and it worked perfectly!.
Solution:

```
static void click(GtkWidget *widget,GdkEvent  *event, gpointer  data){
 cout << "Int value is: " << GPOINTER_TO_INT(data) << endl;
}

int main(){
   gtk_init(0,0);
   //......... MORE CODE ......
   GtkWidget* label  = gtk_image_menu_item_new_with_label(text);
   int value = 50509;
   g_signal_connect(label, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(click), GINT_TO_POINTER(value));
   //......... MORE CODE ......
   gtk_main();
}
```

Thanks @gerhardh for commenting.

Comment: Why do you pass an integer as a pointer? You can still pass it as an address. You just need to cast `gpointer` to `long *`. Either with `(long*)data` or the C++ equivalent.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I tried that too, but I didn't get any success, it kept breaking the real value, the only solution I found was with "int".

Comment: If you use `GSIZE_TO_POINTER()` and`GPOINTER_TO_SIZE()` ?